# Change View function Frappe.js Gantt Chart - not defined error

Tags: javascript

Trying to implement a view selection function in my gantt chart. In the documentation https://frappe.io/gantt it shows the example:

```
gantt.change_view_mode('Week') // Quarter Day, Half Day, Day, Week, Month
```

I have index html :

```
<head>
<script src="dist/frappe-gantt.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
    $(".btn-group").on("click", "button", function() {
$btn = $(this);
var mode = $btn.text();
gantt.change_view_mode(mode);
console.log(mode);
$btn.parent().find('button').removeClass('active');
$btn.addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

`gantt.change_view_mode(mode);` Is returning the following error: Uncaught Reference Error: gantt is not defined

frappe-gantt.js:

```
var Gantt = (function () {
'use strict';

...


    refresh(tasks) {
        this.setup_tasks(tasks);
        this.change_view_mode();
    }

    change_view_mode(mode = this.options.view_mode) {

      console.log(this.options.view_mode);
        this.update_view_scale(mode);
        this.setup_dates();
        this.render();
        // fire viewmode_change event
        this.trigger_event('view_change', [mode]);
    }

    update_view_scale(view_mode) {
        this.options.view_mode = view_mode;

        if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.DAY) {
            this.options.step = 24;
            this.options.column_width = 38;
        } else if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.HALF_DAY) {
            this.options.step = 24 / 2;
            this.options.column_width = 38;
        } else if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.QUARTER_DAY) {
            this.options.step = 24 / 4;
            this.options.column_width = 38;
        } else if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.WEEK) {
            this.options.step = 24 * 7;
            this.options.column_width = 140;
        } else if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.MONTH) {
            this.options.step = 24 * 30;
            this.options.column_width = 120;
        } else if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.YEAR) {
            this.options.step = 24 * 365;
            this.options.column_width = 120;
        }
    }

    setup_dates() {
        this.setup_gantt_dates();
        this.setup_date_values();
    }
```

I have tried changing it to `Gantt.change_view_mode(mode);` But that returns: TypeError: Gantt.change_view_mode is not a function

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already figured it out, but for anybody facing the same problem: You have to initialize the Gantt opject, like so:

```
var tasks = [
  {
    id: 'Task 1',
    name: 'Redesign website',
    start: '2016-12-28',
    end: '2016-12-31',
    progress: 20,
    dependencies: 'Task 2, Task 3'
  },
  {
    id: 'Task 2',
    ...
  }
]
var gantt = new Gantt("#id-of-your-svg-element", tasks);
```

This is information I got from the documentation you also mentioned: https://frappe.io/gantt

Answer (score 0):

You can add button click event directly after you declare the new Gantt object.

```
    var gantt_chart = new Gantt(".gantt-target", tasks, {
        on_click: task => {
            console.log(task);
        },
        on_date_change: (task, start, end) => {
            console.log(task, start, end);
        },
        on_progress_change: (task, progress) => {
            console.log(task, progress);
        },
        on_view_change: (mode) => {
            console.log(mode);
        },
        view_mode: 'Month',
        language: 'en'
    });
    console.log(gantt_chart);

    $(document).on("click", ".btn", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $btn = $(this);
        var mode = $btn.text();
        gantt_chart.change_view_mode(mode);
        console.log(mode);
        $btn.parent().find('button').removeClass('active');
        $btn.addClass('active');
    });
```